# Using methods on vuex getter

Tags: vue.js, typeerror, getter, vuex

I am trying to do a [.find()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) method on a [Vuex getter](https://vuex.vuejs.org/en/getters.html).
However when I do so, it gives me the following error:

```js
Uncaught TypeError: ur.find is not a function
```

I have followed the docs and I cannot seem to understand why I cannot do methods like .find() or .forEach() on the user-Object provided by the vuex Getter. 
Am I doing something wrong, or is this type of thinking out of the scope?

This is an example of my mixin `auth.js`

```js
export const auth = {
    methods: {
        y(r){
            const ur = this.$store.getters.getUserRoles;
            console.log(ur); // Returns {__ob__: Observer}...
            ur.find( uRole => { // ur.find is not a function
                return uRole === r
            })
        }
    }
};
```

And this is my Vuex instance from the main vue; `app.js`

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
    state: {
        user: {}
    },
    mutations: {
        setUser (state, data) {
            state.user = data;
        },
    },
    getters: {
        getUserRoles(state){
            return state.user.roles;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        getUser ({commit}) {
            axios.get('/api/user').then(response => {
                const data = response.data.data;
                commit('setUser', data);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

The response from `/api/user`:

```js
{
  admin: true,
  projectManager: false,
  timeAdmin: false
}
```

Comment: make sure `ur` is of array type, I usually use `findIndex` and it works

Comment: Ah, really good point @samayo! I had to do Object.values(ur) in order to make it work. However, my total idea of this logic is totally wrong, so this example is not working. But regarding the question, you solved it! Thank you :)

Comment: I found your `.findIndex()` idea to be quite interesting @samayo. I had initially thought and written my logic wrong, but with your `.findIndex()` idea, it does do the job. Great thinking! :D But one can have multiple roles, so simply using `.findIndex()` does not work in my case :) But thank you for great input!

Comment: Glad it is working for you almost. I think you can add more ways to filter inside `.findIndex()` but maybe your architecture is slightly complex, in which case you might be better of creating your own custom logic. cheers :)